# What is distinction between Functional Linear Regression and Functional Linear Models?

Tags: statistics, regression, mathematical-modeling

Thanks in advance for the help.

I want to make sure that I understand two concepts correctly.  A functional linear model is a particular type of linear model while functional linear regression is the act of finding the coefficients of a functional linear model.  Is this correct of distinguishing these two terms?

I understand what functional linear models are, I just want to make sure that my understanding of the terminology is correct.

Comment: Could you provide a reference or give a more precise definition of the two concepts you mention?

Comment: Also, you might get better answers to this question on http://stats.stackexchange.com/.